# How do I list all tables in postgres, across schemas

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, command-prompt

I'm trying to list all tables in a database.  \dt isn't doing it, maybe because of name collisions.  I've tried many commands, but when two tables in different schemas share a name, only one gets listed by \dt:

```
CREATE DATABASE tester;
\c tester
CREATE SCHEMA hid1;
CREATE SCHEMA hid2;
CREATE TABLE a (a int);
CREATE TABLE b (a int);
CREATE TABLE hid1.a (a int);
CREATE TABLE hid1.b (a int);
CREATE TABLE hid1.c (a int);
CREATE TABLE hid2.a (a int);
CREATE TABLE hid2.d (a int);
\dt
SET search_path TO public,hid1,hid2;
\dt
SET search_path TO hid1,public,hid2;
\dt
SET search_path TO hid2,hid1,public;
\dt
```

i.e.

```
tester=# \dt
       List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  | Owner
--------+------+-------+-------
 hid1   | a    | table | bob
 hid1   | b    | table | bob
 hid1   | c    | table | bob
 hid2   | d    | table | bob
(4 rows)

tester=# SET search_path TO hid2,hid1,public;
SET
tester=# \dt
       List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  | Owner
--------+------+-------+-------
 hid1   | b    | table | bob
 hid1   | c    | table | bob
 hid2   | a    | table | bob
 hid2   | d    | table | bob
(4 rows)
```

See how three tables are being masked?  My understanding is that schemas are namespaces.  Is that where I'm going wrong?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ask for all tables in all schemas `*`

```
\dt *.*
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to query the information_schema. This gives you a lot of options for filter and sorting using SQL.

```
select table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
from information_schema.tables;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname="yourschemaname";
```

Comment: you should use single quotes for values, like
`SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname='yourschemaname';`